# Best way to model this management

Tags: uml, class-diagram

I'm new to UML, and I've been working on a class diagram that manages a train station (creation of stations, workers, etc). I was wondering if it would be better to model it like this:

[image: model 1]

Or like this:

[image: model 2]

Thank you in advance for any help provided

Comment: I'm afraid you've provided to few information. It is also somewhat opinion based - when methods offered by a class should be extracted to an interface rather than presented within the class. Just one remark - if you eventually decide to use the second approach, make sure to make "Management" an interface (and better call it Manageable") and present it as provided interface of a StationWorker (btw I'm not even sure if this shouldn't be required interface rather than provided for it).

Answer (score 1):

Your first example has invalid operations. Each operation is invoked in the context of an instance of a `StationWorker` class, so it makes no sense to pass in an `id` as a parameter, as if you were going to search for a database record and do something to it. Each instance should already know its `id`.

As @Gagnus pointed out, you need to elaborate more classes. These classes should have associations between them, with each of those "attributes" showing up at the far end of an association with a multiplicity, instead of inside the class itself.

Comment: You should name the child: association role.

Comment: What child are you referring to?

Comment: Oh. German proverb ;-) What you call _those "attributes"_. Those are actually association roles.

Comment: Actually, I don't think they are called that in UML 2. They are properties that are association ends. I'd have to look, but I think "role" is only used in composite structures now.

Comment: See on p. 232 and on p. 181

Comment: The word "role" may not mean what you think anymore. At a quick glance, p. 232 looks to be about composite structures.

Comment: No. 11.9.7 is about associations. And the diagram on p. 181 (see ConnectableElement) clearly states _role_ as the name.

Comment: Nope, that's still in the context of connectors and composite structure. In UML 2.5, a part plays the role of an association or a property, which may be an association end or an attribute.

Comment: P. 181: ConnectorEnd-ConnectableElement has +role. Has nothing to do with composition

Comment: That kind of role is a different thing. You are looking in the wrong section. Go back to the section on classes and associations.

Comment: The relevant section is 9.9.17.1: "A Property is a StructuralFeature. A Property related by ownedAttribute to a Classifier (other than an association) represents an attribute and might also represent an association end. It relates an instance of the Classifier to a value or set of values of the type of the attribute. A Property related by memberEnd to an Association represents an end of the Association."

Notice how the spec itself has repeating subsections that list "Attributes" and "Association Ends". The word "role" is only used in the context of things in composite structures.

Comment: I'll take that as it is. This spec is really no digestive. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You should start not by elaborating of ONE class, but by all classes definition, classes relations definitions, later drawing the connections between classes and only after that the elaboration of classes one after another.